# How to use pandoc-crossref with Hakyll

Tags: haskell, pandoc, hakyll

I'm trying out [Hakyll](https://jaspervdj.be/hakyll/) for an academia-and-math-heavy static website. I'd like to use [pandoc-crossref](https://github.com/lierdakil/pandoc-crossref) for cross-references to equations.

What is the simplest way to include `pandoc-crossref` into the compiler chain?

So far, I was able to integrate a bibliography into the compiler like so

```hs
pandocComplilerWithBibAndOptions :: Compiler (Item String)
pandocComplilerWithBibAndOptions = do
    csl <- load $ fromFilePath "apa.csl"
    bib <- load $ fromFilePath "bibliography.bib"
    fmap write (getResourceString >>= read csl bib)
    where
        read = readPandocBiblio readerOptions
        write = writePandocWith writerOptions
        readerOptions = defaultHakyllReaderOptions {
            readerExtensions = newExtentions <> pandocExtensions
        }
        writerOptions = defaultHakyllWriterOptions {
            writerExtensions = newExtentions <> pandocExtensions,
            writerHTMLMathMethod = MathJax ""
        }
        newExtentions = extensionsFromList  [Ext_tex_math_double_backslash,
                                             Ext_citations,
                                             Ext_latex_macros]

main :: IO ()
main = hakyll $ do
    ...

    match "posts/*" $ do
        route $ setExtension "html"
        compile $ pandocComplilerWithBibAndOptions
            >>= loadAndApplyTemplate "templates/post.html"    postCtx
            >>= loadAndApplyTemplate "templates/default.html" postCtx
            >>= relativizeUrls

    match "*.bib" $ compile biblioCompiler
    match "*.csl" $ compile cslCompiler

   ...
```

While this works nicely, I am clueless on how to integrate the cross-references. My best bet would be to express it as some kind of transform and use `pandocCompileWithTransformM`, but then i wouldn't know how to integrate the bibliography.

Answer (score 3):

#### Using the `Text.Pandoc.CrossRef` API

```
import Text.Pandoc.CrossRef
import Text.Pandoc.Definition (Pandoc) -- pandoc-types

crossRef :: Pandoc -> Pandoc
crossRef = runCrossRef meta Nothing defaultCrossRefAction
  where
    meta = defaultMeta  -- Settings for crossref rendering
```

Try inserting this between `read` and `write`:

```
    fmap (write . fmap crossRef) (getResourceString >>= read csl bib)
```

---

#### Using the `pandoc-crossref` executable

`pandoc-crossref` provides a filter as an executable.

The pandoc library has a function [`applyFilters`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/pandoc-2.19.2/docs/Text-Pandoc-App.html#v:applyFilters) that lets you run such filters by providing the path to the executable.

```
applyFilters :: ... -> Pandoc -> m Pandoc
```

that you can insert between your `read` and `write`.

```
-- 
filterCrossRef :: Pandoc -> PandocIO Pandoc
filterCrossRef = applyFilters env ["pandoc-crossref"] []
```

There are a few extra steps needed to embed this into the hakyll `Compiler` monad (probably `recompilingUnsafeCompiler` in hakyll and something from `PandocIO` to `IO` in pandoc).

Comment: Thanks, but it's not at all clear to me how to combine this function with any of the api of pandoc-crossref: https://hackage.haskell.org/package/pandoc-crossref-0.3.13.0/docs/Text-Pandoc-CrossRef.html .

Comment: OK I updated my answer with more detailed steps.

Comment: I have overseen something. Turn's out that pandoc-crossref has to process the document _before_ citeproc. With the above, citations with [@...] are not processed.

Comment: Do you mean that `crossRef` has to happen somewhere in the middle of `read`?

Comment: yeah, before `readPandocBiblio`. As citations and cross references use the same syntax, crossref as to run over the document before citeproc (before the citations are processed) as mentioned [here](https://lierdakil.github.io/pandoc-crossref/#citeproc-and-pandoc-crossref).

Answer (score 0):

For better visibility (I found this answer when googling for a similar problem) here is my solution for `pandocCompiler` users:

For `pandocCompiler` users here's the code that solved the problem for me:

```
pandocCompilerWithTransformM defaultHakyllReaderOptions defaultHakyllWriterOptions plantumlFilter
  where
    plantumlFilter = recompilingUnsafeCompiler
      . runIOorExplode
      . applyFilters noEngine def
          [JSONFilter "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandoc_plantuml_filter.py"]
          []
```